# Oracle query for get total issue card number which was canceled before

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to show up total number of agent card number reissue which agents canceled the card before. I have three types of card status READY,CANCEL,BLOCK. So I only need to get READY status card as reissue. How can I get agents which card canceled before and reissued between the date 23/11/2019 to 25/11/2019. Here is below my query to get all cards as canceled

can you please help me for this?

Comment: Cancelled and reissue of card both should be between specified date?

Comment: @Tejash yes should be between the date

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need [`LEAD()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions#lag) and [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/row_number-analytic-function) analytic functions :

```
SELECT agent_id,cardnumber,cardtype,dateofissue,cardstatus
  FROM
  (
   SELECT cu.agent_id,cu.cardnumber,cu.cardtype,cu.dateofissue,cu.cardstatus,
          LEAD(cu.cardstatus,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cu.cardnumber ORDER BY cu.dateofissue DESC) as pre_cardstatus,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cu.cardnumber ORDER BY cu.dateofissue DESC) as rn
     FROM eofficeuat.cardprintlog_user cu
     JOIN eofficeuat.cnf_agents ca ON cu.agent_id = ca.agent_id
     JOIN eofficeuat.agent_types at ON ca.agent_type_id = at.agent_type_id
    WHERE at.agent_type_id='12'       
      AND dateofissue BETWEEN date'2019-11-23' AND date'2019-11-25'
   )
  WHERE pre_cardstatus = 'CANCEL' 
    AND cardstatus='READY' 
    AND rn = 1
```

Comment: showing me error "table or view does not exist". Can you update it like this please for table names eofficeuat.cardprintlog_user.table_name?

Comment: well, the schema name is related to own your database's structure, I just removed for simplicity, you can add by yourself. If you want I'm adding @mdkamrul

Comment: now getting this error 

ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 11

Comment: add aliases `cu` for returning columns within the subquery @mdkamrul

Comment: ok, I have run it not zero row retuned, I want total card canceled and reissued please

Comment: it's hard to interpret without sample data @mdkamrul